# How do I start a porstgresql server on my localhost to access it with prisma

Tags: postgresql, psql, prisma

I want to use prisma with a simple postgresql database locally.
I installed postgres and I have a database I can access with the psql shell.
When I try to connect to this database, I get the following error:

> Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Do I somehow have to start the database server to access it?